Elliptic curve over global function field: poles of $j$-function & ramification of torsion fields
Let $E/ \Bbb C(t)$ be an elliptic curve over $ \Bbb C(t)$ with nonconstant $j$-invariant $j_E \in \Bbb C(t)-\Bbb C$ and $p>2$ some prime such that it is bigger than an order of a pole $v$ of $j_E$. Assume that the action of $G:={\rm Gal}\bigl(\overline{{\mathbb C}(t)}\big/{\mathbb C}(t)\bigr)$ on the $p$-torsion $E[p]$ is Abelian, ie the image of $G$ in $ \text{Aut}(E[p])={\rm SL}_2({\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z})$ (...as we are in char $0$) is Abelian.
This image can be naturally identified with Galois group $G_p$ of the extension $\Bbb C(t)(E[p])/\Bbb C(t)$ obtained by adjoining all coordinates of $E[p]$ (naturally living in $\overline{{\mathbb C}(t)}$) to $\Bbb C(t)$, right?
Now Here is claimed that under the assumptions above there exist a $p$-cycle $C_p \cong \Bbb Z/p$ in $G_p$ which is ramified at the pole of $j_E$.
(Firstly as "side question" (...which essentially is  already posed here), on the phrase that a "$p$-cycle is ramified at a pole", so far I understand this correctly, this ramification of such $p$-cycle $C_p$ at a pole $v$ (regarded as a valuation of global field $\Bbb C(t)$) of $j_E$ phrased in more "down-to-earth" terms means that the field extension $K(C_p)/ \Bbb C(t)$ corresponding to $C_p$ via Galois correspondence ramifies over $v$ ($=$ a pole of $j_E$) in sense of usual algebraic number theory.
Is this exactly what is here meant by "$p$-cycle ramifies at pole of $j_E$"?)
If yes, my central question is - motivated strongly by the concrete problem phrased in the linked question - what do we know in broader sense about the connection of Galois theory of extensions of type $\Bbb C(t)(E[p])/\Bbb C(t)$ ( ie obtained by adding $p$-torsion pts) &  and the "information" included in "divisorial data" of $j_E$ (poles & zeroes)? More specifically, my focus lies principally on ramification behavoir of subextensions.
In short, is there any theory tracking relations of zeores/poles of $j_E$ function of elliptic curve over global field with ramification behavior of fields/subfields obtained by adjoining certain torsion points of the curve?
#EDIT: as Chris Wuthrich pointed out this is rather similar to the question linked above I posed before. The difference is that here I'm asking about the "big picture" for the relations between $j$- invariant & ramification data for the Galois theory of torsion fields, which would - in ideal case - give an answer why the "specific" statement I questioned in linked question should hold more less as immediate consequence.

@ChrisWuthrich: my initial motivation to pose this question separately was to focus  more broadly on question what we  generally know about Galois theory of extensions of type $\Bbb C(t)(E[p])/\Bbb C(t)$ with focus on ramification behavior of its subgroup. The answer to question you linked - a much "concrete/ specific" question "on point" - should be in ideal case should follow as a consequence. But you are right, I should phrase the slight difference precisely.

@ChrisWuthrich: I tried to elaborate the different flavour of this question in the edit. The previous formulation was as phrased before indeed an almost duplicate, sorry. Is it now a bit clearer?

I believe this question can be closed once you understand the answer to your first question.

@ChrisWuthrich: I agree, but just finally to extract the quintessence from the other question: So once we identify the $K$-points our elliptic curve $E/K$ with corresp Tate curve $L_w^{\times}/q^{\mathbb{Z}}$  (...in general so far I understand this not always possibly, but after approp "twist"; but let's assume for sake of simplicity we can do it) then the extensions of type $K(E[p])/K$ are rather harmless of "uniform" shape $\zeta_p^r\sqrt[p]{q}^r$, so from Galois theoretic side there happens nothing interesting

You confuse local and global.

@ChrisWuthrich: right, I should have written that we have such "uniform" structure only "place wise"

but still (...for local picture the penultimate statement is phrased correctly, right?), this "local data" impose rather restrictive conditions on structure of the global $K(E[p])/K$
